# Same cloud service, same role type, different configurations

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Is it possible to add the same roles (Worker Roles) more than once into the same cloud service with different configurations?

They all handle different things from a service bus, so they have neither public nor private endpoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All instances of the same role within a cloud service must share the same .cscfg configuration.  You could hack around it by externalising some configuration into blob or table storage, which could then be read when a role starts up, by keying a specific instance's settings using its instance number, e.g. Instance1 consumes Service Bus topic "invoice", Instance2 consumes "order", etc.

However, your best bet is to deploy the worker roles with different configurations into multiple cloud services, which will also allow you to scale out each service independently.

Comment: Interesting but not too reliable, and I also need to scale up only specific roles based on the queue load. Nah, bad idea indeed. Thanks for the explanation.